# Не меняется цвет шрифта при клике на таб

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ребят есть 4 таба. При клике на табы переключается контент но шрифт и бордер который я поставил в стилях не работают, то есть при клике на любой из табов должен переключаться контент и меняться цвет шрифта активного таба.

CSS

```
nav{
    width: 200px;
    height: 160px;
    background: #555;
    color:#fff;
}
.nav-tabs label{
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav-tabs span {
    display:block;
}
input[name=select]{
    display:none;
}
input[name=select]:checked +  span {
    border-right: 10px solid #f7803a;
}
  .layout-tabs {
    top: 111px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 160px;
    bottom: 0;
}

.nav-tabs {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 18px;
    margin-top:0;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav-tabs ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-tabs li {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 25px;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Frutiger;
    src: url(fonts/TradeGothicLTStd.otf);
}

.nav-tabs a {
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 10px;
    transition: all .3s;
}
```

HTML

```
                <div id="layout-tabs" class="layout-tabs">
                <nav>
                    <ul class="nav-tabs" id="tabs">
                        <li>
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="select">
                                <span>
                                    <a href="#tabs1" data-toggle="tab" id="tab-1">Videos</a>
                                </span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="select">
                                    <span>
                                        <a href="#tabs2" data-toggle="tab" id="tab-2">collection</a>
                                    </span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="select">
                                    <span>
                                        <a href="#tabs3"  data-toggle="tab" id="tab-3">lookbook</a>
                                    </span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="select">
                                    <span>
                                        <a href="#tabs4" data-toggle="tab" id="tab-4">Find a store</a>
                                    </span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
```

JS

```
 var tabsLink = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-tabs  a'),
    tabsElement = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-pane'),
    photoElements = document.querySelectorAll('.col-pr'),
    i;

tabsElement[0].classList.add('tab-open');

var showTabs = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetElement = document.querySelectorAll(this.getAttribute('href'));
    for (i = 0; i < targetElement.length; i++) {

        if (targetElement[i].classList.contains('tab-open')) {
            return false;
        } else targetElement[i].classList.add('tab-open');
    }

    targetElement = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-pane.tab-open:not(" + this.getAttribute('href') + ")");
    for (i = 0; i < targetElement.length; i++) {
        targetElement[i].classList.remove('tab-open');
    }
};
```

Самое интересное , что если убрать ссылки на табы внутри span-a `<a href="#tabs1" data-toggle="tab" id="tab-1">Videos</a>` и т.д то при клике на табы будет меняться цвет шрифта , но не будут переключаться сами табы между собой, в чем ошибка и как исправить ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [При клике на табы контент не переключается](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/738854/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f)

Comment: @Air вопрос удален ! Вы вчера удалили свой ответ можете добавить заново чтобы я посмотрел ?

Comment: мой ответ тебе не поможет, потому, что там все по другому, ты лучше учи  html css и js... это не мое дело, что да как ты делаешь.   но код у тебя очень плох...  ты не учитываешь того, что все что ты сделал, ты делал не сам, тебе помогают другие, но каждый делает по своему, не зная глубины проблемы... вот и вся проблема...

Comment: @Air я все сделал сам кроме вот этого поэтому такая каша и случилась .

Comment: я про JS, а не про всю разметку...

Comment: так в этом вопросе можно и без js это сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здравствуйте. Вот привет пример таб. Стилизуйте под себя и не нужно никакого  js)

```css
.tabs {
            min-width: 320px;
            max-width: 800px;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        /* Стили секций с содержанием */
        
        .tabs > section {
            display: none;
            padding: 15px;
            background: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
        }
        
        .tabs > section > p {
            margin: 0 0 5px;
            line-height: 1.5;
            color: #383838;
            /* прикрутим анимацию */
            -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
            animation-duration: 1s;
            -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
            animation-fill-mode: both;
            -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
            animation-name: fadeIn;
        }
        /* Описываем анимацию свойства opacity */
        
        @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
            from {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            to {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
        
        @keyframes fadeIn {
            from {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            to {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
        
        /* Прячем чекбоксы */
        
        .tabs > input {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
        }
        /* Стили переключателей вкладок (табов) */
        
        .tabs > label {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0 0 -1px;
            padding: 15px 25px;
            font-weight: 600;
            text-align: center;
            color: #aaa;
            border: 0px solid #ddd;
            border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
            background: #f1f1f1;
            border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
        }
        /* Шрифт-иконки от Font Awesome в формате Unicode */
        
        .tabs > label:before {
            font-family: fontawesome;
            font-weight: normal;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        
        /* Изменения стиля переключателей вкладок при наведении */
        
        .tabs > label:hover {
            color: #888;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        /* Стили для активной вкладки */
        
        .tabs > input:checked + label {
            color: #555;
            border-top: 1px solid #009933;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
            background: #fff;
        }
        /* Активация секций с помощью псевдокласса :checked */
        
        #tab1:checked ~ #content-tab1,
        #tab2:checked ~ #content-tab2 {
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
            <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
            <label for="tab1">Wordpress</label>
            <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
            <label for="tab2">Windows</label>

            <section id="content-tab1">
                <p> WordPress — </p>
            </section>
            <section id="content-tab2">
                <p> Microsoft Windows</p>
            </section>
           
        </div>
```